# Creating a new column in a Python Pandas DataFrame, which contains the min date, for which the rows item appeared

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling to create a new column in a DataFrame that's supposed to be the first date for which the rows item was seen in the data set.

Ex:
DataFrame: df
Columns: Dates| Inquiries/Questions|Number of times asked

I'd like to add a new date that is df[First Instance] in which an inquiry/question arose. But clearly this is easier said than done.

I've tried list comprehensions, creating a subdata frame from inquires and dates, grouping on inquiries, outputting a max to generate a dictionary and then map the values back to the inquires as keys, but that added a bunch of Nan values for some reason. I'm at a loss here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The purpose of the data frame is to have a running report where I can assess stats for new vs old questions, and the "First Day" component is of the utmost importance and my biggest hurdle to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates': [datetime.today() - timedelta(days=random.randint(0, 100)) for _ in range(20)],
    'Inquiries/Questions': [random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c']) for _ in range(20)],
    'Number of times asked': [random.randint(1, 3) for _ in range(20)]
})

df.head()
```

**Outputs:**

```
                       Dates Inquiries/Questions  Number of times asked
0 2020-02-22 23:50:06.809304                   c                      2
1 2020-05-02 23:50:06.809334                   b                      3
2 2020-03-15 23:50:06.809343                   c                      1
3 2020-03-03 23:50:06.809351                   b                      1
4 2020-05-07 23:50:06.809358                   b                      1
```

**Solution**

```
g = df.groupby('Inquiries/Questions')['Dates'].min()
df['First_Day'] = df['Inquiries/Questions'].apply(lambda x: g[x])
df.head()
```

Comment: I've gotten this far, but how would I add these data as a new column "First Day", to the original DataFrame where they're matched to the inquires/questions?

Comment: Thank You! This is on the money.

Can you allude to how the x is being chosen to map the date to the inquiry?

.apply is essentially mapping the second column output from the groupby, based on the inquiries as an index right? But how does x in g[x] = Dates/Second column? Is it because of the column headers lining up, and or series values?

Comment: Well, “g” is a series acting like a sort of dictionary. The indexes are a, b and c, and the values are the first dates for those three categories. The lambda function just works to take in an inquiry (E.g. “a”), and returns the corresponding first date. The apply bit just goes through all the values in the Inquiries and, for each one, returns that items shortest date, that’s just how apply works. If you take away the df[‘First_Day’] = part, you’ll see that it’s just a series that is indexes the same way as your data-frame.

Comment: Or, more precisely, when you apply on a data frame column, the input and output will have the same index, which means they’ll always line up like that